# My module wont show up.what could be the error?

Tags: module

My module is about filtering Payment Method when customer selects one of the shipping methods.
Namespace: Insync

Module-Name: Paymentfilter

Config.xml (app/code/local/Insync/Paymentfilter/etc) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Insync_Paymentfilter>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Insync_Paymentfilter>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Insync_Paymentfilter_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Observer.php (app/code/local/Insync/Paymentfilter/Model) :

```
class Insync_Paymentfilter_Model_Observer {

public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {


$event           = $observer->getEvent();
$method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
$result          = $event->getResult();
$carriers = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

        if ($carriers == 'tablerate' ){
                if($method->getCode() == 'checkmo' OR $method->getCode() == 'ccsave'){
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                }else{
                    $result->isAvailable = false;
                }
            }

         }
}
```

Insync_Paymentfilter.xml (app/etc/modules)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Insync_Paymentfilter>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Insync_Paymentfilter>
</modules>
</config>
```

The purpose of module is when customer selects 'tablerate' as shipping method he would be ONLY given two Payment Methods i.e

> Check/Money Order (checkmo)

and

> Credit Card (ccsave)

Comment: what is <!--?xml version="1.0"?--> at the top of your app/etc/modules file?

Comment: by "module won't show up" you mean it does nothing or is not picked up by magento?

Comment: Marius it neither gets showed up in Advanced section nor works.

Comment: did you create the file `app/etc/modules/Insync_Paymentfilter.xml`? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: @Marius its already there.read my question i have included all essential files but its not working.can you please check my config.xml to make sure its correct?

Comment: I read the question. I just wanted to make sure. The only reason a module would not appear in the advanced section is that if the file from `app/etc/modules` is not there or is not readable or is not valid, or if the cache is not cleared. The `config.xml` can be completely screwed up. If the declaration file `app/etc/modules` is there and is valid and is readable the rest of the module is not important. It should show up in the advanced section.

Comment: @Marius You are right. I edited and removed first line from my insync_paymentfilter.xml it now shows up in Advanced section but it does not work the way it is supposed to do.Like when I select tablerate shipping as shipping method i am getting all payment methods intead of just two defined in my observer.php

Comment: so the question itself it solved right?

Comment: You can look into the method restrictAdminBillingAgreementUsage in Mage_Sales_Model_Oberver class, you'll get an idea where you are going wrong with this approach, but still try to raise a different question for this condition, as it no longer aligns with the initial question.